# Prolog Sudoku Ex. High Level

Tags: prolog, sudoku

School assignment to write a sudoku solver. I've broken the problem down into a few steps. Code for the "main" function is below. As for each of the individual steps, they work, but Im wondering how I unify the unbound variable in my list with the number I compute. I then wish to pass this list to work with in the next call. If the question is not entirely clear,  tell me and I will elaborate. Thanks

code:

I know the code below is wrong, as I think I'm just passing my original sudoku list. A sudoku list is a list of lists, e.g.

```
 [[1,_,_,8,_,4,_,_,_],
  [_,2,_,_,_,_,4,5,6],
  [_,_,3,2,_,5,_,_,_],
  [_,_,_,4,_,_,8,_,5],
  [7,8,9,_,5,_,_,_,_],
  [_,_,_,_,_,6,2,_,3],
  [8,_,1,_,_,_,7,_,_],
  [_,_,_,1,2,3,_,8,_],
  [2,_,5,_,_,_,_,_,9]]
```

Code:

```
fill(List) :- 
    findVar(V,List,0,X,Y,Sub), % Find a variable to bind
    difference([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],Sub,Choices), % Find numbers not yet in row
    random(Choices,N), % Select random number from available numbers
    V = N,
    check(List,X,Y), % Check for correctness
    fill(List).
```

Comment: When is this code supposed to terminate?

Comment: Right now, I have fill(_):-. Should have included that.

Comment: When is that NOT supposed to succeed?

Comment: When every free variable in the list has been filled in. The way my algorithm works right now is. 1. Find first free variable. 2. Find its row and calculate which numbers are still available for picking. 3. Select a random number out of the choices. 4. Check if the sudoku with the chosen number is correct (does not violate the sudoku rules). 5. If it was correct, go to next free variable, if not, try another number (still have to implement this if).